# Set variable to return of callback listener

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, generator, redux-saga

I'm using firebase to handle auth in my application. Firebase has a listener that executes a callback anytime the authentication status changes. I have that in a firebase utils file:

```
export default {
    ...

    authChanged: (callback) =>{
        return firebaseAuth.onAuthStateChanged(callback);
    },

    ...
}
```

When a user logs in/out the callback executes. I'm trying to handle this observer in redux-saga,sending an event to my reducer whenever firebase tells me the status changes. The problem I'm running into is that I can't determine how to corral the dynamic return value of that observer. Right now I'm doing this:

```
export function* loginState(){
    Firebaseutils.authChanged(function(user){
        if(user){
            yield put({type: 'LOGGED_IN', user: {user.email, user.uid}})
        }else{
            yield put({type: 'LOGGED_OUT'})
        }
    });
}
```

I've confirmed the if/else conditionals work (just logging to console when status changes), but I get an error if I try to use yields. It's either a bug or I'm going against a rule I'm not clear on. Any other way to set this up? It seems like from a best practice perspective this really needs to be handled by redux-sagas.

Comment: Did you figure a solution?

Answer (score 0):

You can only use `yield` inside a generator function. And unlike variables and functions, `yield` is not available inside a nested function, which your callback function is.

You can just dispatch the actions with normal dispatch.